# Material Ui Field picker

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create something like this

[image]

So I can choose between fields, how is it possible to create something like this in material ui?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I assume you’re not asking that really. If you’re asking how, it becomes too broad for Stack Overflow. If you’re asking where to get a component that does this it’s also off topic. So unfortunately your question doesn’t seem to be suitable here but at least edit it to include some more details of your issue if “yes” isn’t enough to answer it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen,  I've read the MateriaUi Documentation didn't find how to create something like this.
Maybe i missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component for each button, and give it a `className` that defines background color like the unmarked ones at your image. `className` should be `state` property.

After that inside`onClick`change that `state`property to the css class that has red background.

For example:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {buttonDesign: "not-selected"};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        if (this.state.buttonDesign == "selected"){
            this.setState({
            buttonDesign: "not-selected"
          });
        }
        else if (this.state.buttonDesign == "not-selected"){
            this.setState({
            buttonDesign: "selected"
          });
        } 
        }
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <button className={this.state.buttonDesign} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                "your button name"
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

and in your css file you should have something like this:

```
.not-selected {
  background-color : #ff9191; // or your color
}
.selected{
  background-color: #ff0000; // or your color
}
```

And you would need some logic to track which ones have been selected.

Comment: is there a way to do it staticly ?

Comment: how do you mean ?

Comment: Just with Material-ui and the chip component.
I know all the data that i'm going to use so i want to put them in a sort of array, and display them, so i can choose between them.